# Removing outliers is causing a problem in later code execution

Tags: r

I am using the data found here: https://www.kaggle.com/cdc/behavioral-risk-factor-surveillance-system. In my R studio, I have named the csv file, BRFSS2015. Below is the code I am trying to execute. First, I identify outliers in a certain variable `PA1MIN` and remove them. Then, using another variable `MARITAL`, I try to run a comparison across groups. For `MARITAL`, I am only considering values 1-6. I am also removing NAs from `PA1MIN_noout`. I had previously converted `MARITAL` to a factor using:

```
MARITAL <- c('MARITAL')
BRFSS2015[MARITAL] <- lapply(BRFSS2015[MARITAL],factor)
```

Then I ran the remaining code below:

```
PA1MIN_<-BRFSS2015$PA1MIN_
upper_PA1MIN_<-quantile(PA1MIN_,0.997,na.rm=TRUE)
lower_PA1MIN_<-quantile(PA1MIN_,0.003,na.rm=TRUE)
out_PA1MIN_<-which(PA1MIN_>upper_PA1MIN_|PA1MIN_<lower_PA1MIN_)
PA1MIN_noout<-PA1MIN_[-out_PA1MIN_]

BRFSS2015%>%
filter(!is.na(PA1MIN_noout), MARITAL %in% 1:6)%>%
mutate(married = MARITAL == 1, 
       divorced = MARITAL == 2,
       widowed = MARITAL == 3,
       separated = MARITAL == 4,
       never_married = MARITAL == 5,
       unmarried_couple = MARITAL == 6) %>%
group_by(married,divorced,widowed,separated,never_married,unmarried_couple) %>%
summarize(mean = mean(PA1MIN_noout),
          sd = sd(PA1MIN_noout),
          min = min(PA1MIN_noout),
          max = max(PA1MIN_noout),
          .groups = "drop")%>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits=2)
```

I am getting output:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = !is.na(PA1MIN_noout)`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 441456 or 1, not size 440591.
```

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: The outliers must be removed from the data set, not  from one of its columns. Try `BRFSS2015_noout<-BRFSS2015[-BRFSS2015, ]` then use this data subset, not the original one. (All of this assuming you really should/want to remove outliers.)

Comment: Thank you. When I use this syntax, I get this error: Input:  `BRFSS2015_noout<-BRFSS2015[-out_PA1MIN_]` Output: `Error in vectbl_as_col_location(j, length(x), names(x), j_arg = j_arg, :` What is the error now?